# BFS algo python implementaion

Tags: python, depth-first-search

This is my implementation of the BFS Algo , the player is only allowed on 0 and not 1
but it's not working as intended : I get a path but it goes on 1
Here is the code:

```py
from collections import deque

def shortest_path(matrix, start, target):
    rows, cols = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
    queue = deque([start])
    visited = {start}
    distance = {start: 0}
    prev = {start: None}
    min_distance = float('inf')
    closest_cell = None
    
    while queue:
        x, y = queue.popleft()
        if (x, y) == target:
            return construct_path(prev, start, target)
        
        d = abs(x - target[0]) + abs(y - target[1])
        if d < min_distance:
            min_distance = d
            closest_cell = (x,y)
        
        for dx, dy in [(0,1), (0,-1), (1,0), (-1,0)]:
            new_x, new_y = x + dx, y + dy
            if 0 <= new_x < rows and 0 <= new_y < cols and matrix[new_x][new_y] == 0 and (new_x,new_y) not in visited:
                visited.add((new_x,new_y))
                queue.append((new_x,new_y))
                distance[(new_x,new_y)] = distance[(x,y)] + 1
                prev[(new_x,new_y)] = (x,y)
    
    return construct_path(prev, start, closest_cell)

def construct_path(prev, start, target):
    path = []
    while target != start:
        path.append(target)
        target = prev[target]
    path.append(start)
    return path[::-1]

m = [
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

print(shortest_path(m,(0, 1) ,(2, 2)))
```

I got [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
It should be [0,1; 0,0 ;1,0 ;2,0 ;2,1 ;2,2]

Answer (score 1):

You have your rows and columns mixed up when indexing into your matrix.

Changing:`matrix[new_x][new_y]` to `matrix[new_y][new_x]` produces:

`[(0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]`

This makes sense if you think of `y` as vertical (rows) and `x` as horizontal (columns).